# Webkit (Chrome or Safari) way doing AJAX safely on onunload / onbeforeunload

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, safari, webkit, synchronous

In my tests Chrome (and I guess as any other webkit browser probably) is UNABLE to perform an AJAX request BEFORE leaving a page.

Imagine for instance, that you need to clean up something on the server because the user clicked on some link or left the page.

First thing I noticed is that window.onunload DOES NOT work anyhow on Chrome (Webkit?)

Once you are using window.onbeforeunload MAKE SURE you DON'T put in the the body like this:  Cause it is ignored. YOU HAVE TO do window.onbeforeunload=function() {...} to make sure the binding is done (or use jquery or protoype libs for this)

WITHIN your onbeforeunload code a ASYNCHRONOUS Ajax like this WON'T work either:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "dosomething.page");
req.send(null);
```

(although this will WORK in Firefox)

It will work if ONLY if the request is made SYNCHRONOUS like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "dosomething.page",false);
req.send(null);
```

Although keep in mind that synchronous can cause the browser to hang for 2minutes if the server does NOT reply.

Also Firefox DOES NOT seem to work with onunload.

So in the end YOU have to provide with a different code path for each browser or browser family.

I haven't been able to test IE properly on this.
Does anyone know?
Is IE more like Chrome or FF in this? 
or is it different to both as well?

Answer (score 0):

IE seems to work just like Firefox (Gecko) in this particular case:

With this code you can make it work for WebKit, Firefox and IE:

```
// Browser detection
var Browser={
    IE:     !!(window.attachEvent && !window.opera),
    Opera:  !!window.opera,
    WebKit: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('AppleWebKit/') > -1,
    Gecko:  navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('KHTML') == -1,
    MobileSafari: !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Apple.*Mobile.*Safari/)
};

// Ensures the Ajax Get is performed... Asynchronously if possible 
// or Synchronously in WebKit Browsers (otherwise it'll most probably fail)
function ensureAJAXGet(url, args) {
    var async=!Browser.WebKit;
    var finalUrl=url;
    var sep="";
    for (var key in args) {
        sep=(sep=="?")?"&":"?";
    finalUrl=finalUrl+sep+encodeURIComponent(key)+"="+encodeURIComponent(args[key]);
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", finalUrl,async);
    req.send();
    return req;
}

// Sets up an unload function for all browsers to work (onunload or onbeforeunload)
function onUnload(func) {
    if(Browser.WebKit) {
        window.onbeforeunload=func;     
    } else {
        window.onunload=func;
    }
}
```

A test html could be this:

```
var browser="?"
if (Browser.IE) {
    browser="IE";
} else if (Browser.Opera) {
    browser="Opera";
} else if (Browser.WebKit) {
    browser="WebKit";
} else if (Browser.Gecko) {
    browser="Gecko";
} else if (Browser.MobileSafari) {
    browser="MobileSafari"; 
}

function unload() {
    ensureAJAXGet("testajax.jsp", {"browser": browser});
}

onUnload(function() { unload(); });
```

That is:

1. To do something onunload you call onUnload() instead of directly using either window.onload or window.onunload. This ensures that the proper event is used (onbeforeunload in WebKit and onunload on the rest)
2. To sent some GET Ajax on an unload function use ensureAjaxGet() that will be asynchronous AJAX when possible and synchronous when needed (WebKit)